# Float listings in LyX with classicthesis style

Tags: floats, listings, lyx

I can not figure out how to insert floating listings in LyX with (or without) `classicthesis` style.

Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Follow Insert > Program Listing to insert a listing. Then right-click *inside* the listing and choose Settings... > Float (under Main Settings / Placement).

Comment: Thank you for replying. Strangely, it doesn't add any float. Maybe I'm missing some additional settings? I could also just copy/paste from the classicthesis template if I can't figure it out.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "it doesn't add any float". Does it add a listing, but it just doesn't float, or does it not add a listing at all? Do you see the listing in your LyX editor window?

Comment: It does add listing, but when I right click to settings and check the float, then apply > close, it doesn't add any float.

Comment: @m: I can't replicate that problem, so I don't know what you're doing differently.

Comment: @MoHoushmand can you post a minimal example? See e.g. http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=ge65f8c6aee68afc29997421036cde4e92c2821e4b

Comment: @MoHoushmand: We would need the `classicthesis` LyX layout as well.

Comment: http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g861893175bf63159999742105c1c5278615e39569

Comment: @MoHoushmand: The last link didn't include `classicthesis.layout`, so I used [this version](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/downloads) of `classicthesis` for LyX and still I can't replicate your problem.

Comment: Oh sorry about that @Werner.

Comment: http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=gdc4eee9c9568f0eb999742108cbdf110e05605656

Comment: @MoHoushmand: With your version of `classicthesis.layout`, I can't even compile the document.

Comment: @Werner: I can't even open ´classicthesis.layout´, it required some third party software. I don't no what to do with it anyway. Maybe I should download the version you posted earlier and replace the .layout file? But I'm pretty sure I recently dowloaded the package from the repository you suggested .

Comment: @MoHoushmand: All `.layout` files are text files that you should be able to open using even Notepad.

Comment: @MoHoushmand I really think you should use the official version of the CT template from https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis. First test if the template works without making any changes. Compare the pdf you get with the one included in the zip. Read what's in that pdf, it will help you understand how it all works. Then start adding your modifications, and test each and every. Make notes of what you've changed, it might help us figure out what went wrong.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip, I followed you're advice and downloaded the package from the link you postet and read the pdf twice, created a new file, but still have issues with float listing. This is what I do: insert > program listing, then I move the cursor inside the listing, right click in to settings check the float option, then apply and ok. The only thing that happens is that the listing would move slightly to the right as I push the ok button, like it gets  indented or something. Maybe there are some conflict between my macbook air and lyx. I have an older version of lyx with the same problem.

Comment: @MoHoushmand It doesn't matter if anything happens in LyX or not, you're only interested in PDF output. Just do as Werner said.

Comment: @MoHoushmand: I think you may be misinterpreting what is considered a float or not in terms of visuals. You may set something as a float in LyX, but it doesn't change the location within the document/editor. It will only float when compiling to view the output.

Comment: @Werner. I'm really sorry for wasting you're time by being such a newbie. I just realised that I have to insert a caption. Misinterpretation, indeed.